# call external function in python cgi-bin

Tags: python, apache, cgi, torch

I am trying to call a Torch 7 program from within a Python cgi-bin script.

If I run the following Python script from the command line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from subprocess import call
call (['th', 'sample.lua', 'cv/lm_lstm_epoch3.54_0.9324.t7', '-gpuid', '-1', '-primetext', '"אמר הגאון הגרפקא המן איש טוב היה שנאמר"', '-temperature', '1.0', '-length', '1000'])
```

This works fine and I get the following output

> ubuntu@ip-172-31-45-110:/usr/lib/cgi-bin$ python test2.py
>   creating an lstm...
>
> ### seeding with "אמר הגאון הגרפקא המן איש טוב היה שנאמר"
>
> "אמר הגאון הגרפקא המן איש טוב היה שנאמר"זה יקרק ידו מי שכן בלבד ומחללין עליו אותוממנו וזכה זה לא סולד דינר הקדשו מחופה את אשתו מבית הרן וביניהןאבל יום אחד ולמנין שניה ימיבתן ככלום זכותדכתיב אשר בחרם אם אשר עשו לא כל חטאת קמיהבדין נקרא ולא מהוציאה ולא ניקבה לא אמר ליה אם תימצילומר עד דכם ראשון בגובהו הרי ז] נידוןטומאה מידקיסא אי תלמודה ומי איכא למיפרך מהלשרעתו לאהתנאו לא א"ל הכי קאמר אפילושחי ושוברו של מקום הראשוןכסיפו והרי חילין בבית המקדש והיכיממעיטרים אחרינא ועיבור בישראל מי איכא מידיאישתי מירחו דשקיל אמר להו אי שבעים שנה שעוריםעלין א"כ רבי ינאי בר מישראלאמר לו נפש גזר קונשי ב תרצות

However if I try calling Torch 7 from a cgi-bin script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
import os, sys

import cgi, cgitb


print "Content-Type: text/html"
print                
print "<TITLE>CGI script output</TITLE>"

output = ""

output = subprocess.call (['th', 'sample.lua', 'cv/lm_lstm_epoch3.54_0.9324.t7', '-gpuid', '-1', '-primetext', '"אמר הגאון הגרפקא המן איש טוב היה שנאמר"', '-temperature', '1.0', '-length', '1000'])

print output
```

Then I get no output at all to the webpage, there is also no error in the apache error log.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to store the output of the command you are executing. [call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) will not do this. Call will only give you the return code of what you are executing.

```
subprocess.check_output(['th', 'sample.lua', 'cv/lm_lstm_epoch3.54_0.9324.t7', '-gpuid', '-1', '-primetext', '"אמר הגאון הגרפקא המן איש טוב היה שנאמר"', '-temperature', '1.0', '-length', '1000'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now getting a no such file or directory  error although I have chmod'ed 777 everything in cgi-bin and subdirectories called by Torch.

Answer (score -1):

May be you could try [lutorpy](https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy) then you can run the torch code directly with python. You can use require("sample") to import your sample.lua module, and then run the inner function just like you run a python function.